# Global sections of $\mathcal{O}(k)$ are homogeneous polynomials

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, projective-space

I'm trying to find a proof for the following statement, but I'm out of luck.

> For $k\ge 0$ the space $\Gamma(\mathbb{P}^n, \mathcal{O}(k))$ is canonically isomorphic to the space $\mathbb{C}[z_0,\dots,z_n]_k$ of all homogeneous polynomials of degree $k$.

I can't figure out why all global sections $s : \mathbb{P} \to \mathcal{O}(k)$ should be a homogeneous polynomials.

I know that $\mathcal{O}(k) \cong \mathcal{O}(1)^{\otimes k}$ and that $\mathcal{O}(1)$ is the dual of the tautological line bundle $\mathcal{O}(-1)$ on $\mathbb{P}^n$, but this ain't enough for me to be able to prove the statement. If someone here knows where I can find a proof or knows how to prove this I would appreciate that.

Comment: *Hint*: $\mathcal{O}(k)$ is the line bundle that is trivial on the usual open cover of $\mathbb{P}^n$ and the gluing data (transition function) is given by $f\mapsto f\times(z_i/z_j)^k$ between $U_i=(z_i\neq 0)$ and $U_j=(z_j\neq 0)$.

Comment: (i) Do you know how to proceed for $n = 1$ and $n = 2$? If not, do you know about transition functions, and how to find them for $\mathcal{O}(1)$? (ii) If it matters, the isomorphism might not be _canonical_; it depends how much structure you have on the projective space.

Comment: I can't yet produce a proof for neither $n = 1$ or $n = 2$. I know about transition functions and how they determine bundles, but not how to find them for $\mathcal{O}(1)$. As a set what is $\mathcal{O}(1)$? As the dual of $\mathcal{O}(-1)$, the element should be maps $f : \mathcal{O}(-1) \to \mathbb{C}$ right? @AndrewD.Hwang

Comment: The fiber of $\mathcal O(1)$ over an arbitrary point is the dual vector space to the fiber of $\mathcal O(-1)$ over the same point. And if a vector bundle has transition functions $g_{ij}$ then the dual bundle has transition functions $(g_{ij}^T)^{-1}$.